# Using convenience init in Swift instead of abstract in Java and Kotlin

Tags: ios, swift, abstract-class

I am new in iOS development using Swift. I try to create a generic solution for my network layer and viewModel layer. I wrote following code in network layer :

```
typealias ListAPIResponse<T: Decodable> = (Swift.Result<[T]?, DataError>) -> Void

protocol APILogic {
    func getItems<T>(completion: @escaping (ListAPIResponse<T>))
}

class ItemAPI: APILogic {
    
    private let url: String
    
    init(url: String) {
        self.url = url
    }
    
    func getItems<T>(completion: @escaping (ListAPIResponse<T>)) {
        // this prevents AF retrieving cached responses
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        
        AF.request(url)
            .validate()
            .responseDecodable(of: [T].self) { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(.failure(.networkingError(error.localizedDescription)))
                case .success(let schools):
                    completion(.success(schools))
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I have a generic viewModel as follow :

```
class BaseViewModel<T: Decodable> {
    
    @Published private(set) var items: [T]?
    @Published private(set) var error: DataError? = nil
    
    private let apiService: APILogic
    
    init(url: String) {
        self.apiService = ItemAPI(url: url)
    }
    
    func getSchools() {
        apiService.getItems { [weak self] (result:Result<[T]?, DataError>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let schools):
                self?.items = schools ?? []
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.error = error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to have different urls for my network layer, I have following derived classes :

```
class ViewModel1: BaseViewModel<School> {
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(url: Constants.url1)
    }
}

class ViewModel2: BaseViewModel<SchoolSAT> {
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(url: Constants.url2)
    }
}
```

I am coming from Android world using Java and Kotlin, and we have abstract keyword there to handle following logics in base class, but we don't have that in Swift. So is it a common solution to use `convenience init` to handle such a cases? Is there any better solution you can recommend?

Comment: It looks ok - doesn't have to be that way, but not awkward either. I would change 2 things: 1 - use async / await, rather than callback, and 2 - separate a networking layer from view model. I.e. ViewModel to be responsible for "data as it will be displayed", while some other component (e.g. `SchoolEndpoint` class, based on `BaseEndpoint<T>`) is responsible for retrieving and parsing the data.

Comment: @klangfarb thank you for your comment. Should I use schoolEndPoint in ViewModel instead to init ApiLogic? Can you show me your suggestions in code as an answer?